# Ms Access Query to allow for null rows

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-office

In MS Access SQL, I have a query that uses two excel tables, one with all the data and a second as an input, the input fields are names, start date and end date. The query i wrote will return data from the first tale where the name is matched and the date falls between the range of start to end.

The problem is when the start and end date fields are left empty the query returns nothing, i need a query that when the date range is empty it will just match the name and return all dates with the matching name. I attached my query that I have so far

[image: The query I have working]

Comment: Edit your question and include your query as *text*.

Answer (score 1):

You want logic like this:

```
where (sheet1.b1_file_dd > [inputs].start_date or [inputs].start_date is null) and
      (sheet1.b1_file_dd < [inputs].end_date or [inputs].end_date is null)
```

Comment: I think the `or` between the two bracketed clauses should be an `and`.

Comment: @LeeMac . . . I agree.  Thank you.